# Php select from string

Tags: php

Hi I'm new to php and I need a little help

I need to change the text that is between ** in php string and put it between html  tag

```
$text = "this is an *example*";
```

But I really don't know how and i need help

Comment: You should use [a PHP DOM parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

personally I would use explode, you can then piece the sentence back together if the *example* appears in the middle of a sentence

```
<?php
$text = "this is an *example*";
$pieces = explode("*", $text);
echo $pieces[0];
?>
```

Edit:

Since you're looking for what basically amounts to custom BB Code use this

```
$text = "this is an *example*";
$find = '~[\*](.*?)[\*]~s';
$replace = '<span style="color: green">$1</span>';
echo preg_replace($find,$replace,$text);
```

You can add this to a function and have it parse any text that gets passed to it, you can also make the find and replace variables into arrays and add more codes to it

Comment: Thats give me the text between (*) i want to output whole text string but the text between (*) inside a html a tag

Comment: `<?php

$text = "this is an *example*";
$pieces = explode("*", $text);
echo $pieces[0]."<b>".$pieces[1]."</b>";
?>`


Should output the text inbetween the () in a tag

Comment: Works perfectly but i need more help if the * doesn't exist he doesn't change anything

Comment: In the explode function you'll see its split into two sections, the first one is what the function is searching for, in this case its *, change that to what ever you will set for your code. The limitation is that you need to use the same character at the beginning and end of the string if you want it to split the string properly.

Here is a link to the [php documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)

Comment: Well in outputting data from mysql table

Comment: I wanna create a system like green text in 4chan but between two *

Comment: Here is a better piece of code to do that. It uses @jay-blanchard 's regex method only slightly different

`$text = "this is an *example*";
$find = '~[\*](.*?)[\*]~s';
$replace = '<span style="color: green">$1</span>';
echo preg_replace($find,$replace,$text);`

Comment: Thanks ! Exactly what I want! Thank you

Comment: No problem. Glad to help

Comment: If i needed to change the * for example lets say something between > and <

Comment: What do i change?

Comment: ~[\*](.*?)[\*]~s -
Where the code shows [\\*] change that to what you need so it could be like [\&] etc

Answer (score 1):

You really should use a DOM parser for things like this, but if you can guaratee it will always be the `*` character you can use some regex:

```
$text = "this is an *example*";
$regex = '/(?<=\*)(.*?)(?=\*)/';
$replacement = 'ostrich';
$new_text = preg_replace($regex, $replacement, $text);
echo $new_text;
```

Returns

```
this is an *ostrich*
```

Here is how the regex works:

```
Positive Lookbehind (?<=\*)
    \* matches the character * literally (case sensitive)

1st Capturing Group (.*?)
    .*? matches any character (except for line terminators)
     *? Quantifier — Matches between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed (lazy)

Positive Lookahead (?=\*)
    \* matches the character * literally (case sensitive)
```

This regex essentially starts and ends by looking at what is ahead of and behind the search character you specified and leaves those characters intact during the replacement with [`preg_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php).

Comment: What, exactly, do you want? You said *"I need to change the text that is between ** "* and this, does that.

Comment: What i need is to put the text between ** inside a html <a> tag without changing it

Comment: Do the `*` need to be part of the tag?